# How to locate source of exit() call

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm trying to resolve a problem that involves the unexpected exit of a managed Windows service (C#, .NET 4.0).

If the service stops unexpectedly while Visual Studio 2010 is attached to the service's process, VS reports [my service name].exe has exited with code 1 (0x1).

Normally I'd simply search the service code for the exit code. However, in this case the code does not appear to contain any calls to System.Environment.Exit() that could result in an exit code of 1.

How can I find out where (and by connection: why) the process has exited?

In case it's relevant: the service uses some unmanaged objects. Some of the unmanaged objects indirectly interface with hardware.

Comment: Have you tried logging the `StackTrace`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks for your response. How do I get the stack trace? I don't know how/where the service is stopping, and no exception is thrown.

Comment: Just see the link I provided, create a global `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` handler, then in the handler create a new `StackTrace` object which will capture the current stack trace. Save it to a log file.

Comment: Ahh, sorry - I wasn't aware of ProcessExit, and I didn't see it mentioned in your link. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

For detailed  information, about any exception occurred or why it stopped unexpectedly, you need to check windows log from the following location

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools
->Event Viewer->Windows Logs -> Application

Check by your service name under source column

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm aware of the application event logs... but there is no exception. The service is simply stopped with the given exit code. That's why I described the situation as an "unexpected exit" rather than a crash.